# Can I change an object from the master slide only for this slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a presentation, and a set of masterslides. On the master slides I have some lines for a certain representation. The vertical location of these lines should be changed depending on the amount of text (and sometimes I also need less lines so I want to delete some). You can think of it as some kind of itemize-list using lines.

I am used to Indesign, where you can grab an object from the master with some key-combi (I think it was ctrl+shift). This way, you'll have the same objects, but you can move them.

Is there anything like this for powerpoint?

Comment: [This page](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/can-you-edit-master-items-on-slides-other-than-the-master-slide.2580233/) might be useful.  I don't have MS PPT to confirm, but it appears you can't do this in PowerPoint the way you can in InDesign and you'll have to copy and paste.